# Having texture and color shader at the same time in WebGL

Tags: colors, webgl, textures

Let's say I wanted to have two different shapes- one with a color buffer and another with a texture buffer, how woud I write that code out in the shaders since the tutorials made it almost like you could only have one or the other, but not both?

So like in the following code, I have something for the texture and something to make the color blue in another line of code- how would I make that differentiation in this language- I tried using ints to symbolize the choice between the two but it didn't work out very well...

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
     precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));

   // gl_FragColor= vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many different ways you can do this.

- You could write an `if` statement or `? :` expression in the shader to choose one or the other based on some parameter. (It sounds like you tried this but got it wrong somehow — I can't tell what the problem might have been from your question. However, I would avoid using an `int` parameter unless have a specific need for one, because integer computations are not what GPUs are optimized for.)
- You could multiply the texture and uniform color together, and give textured objects a white color and colored objects a white texture. (This is like how the classic “fixed-function pipeline” rendering operates.)
- You could use two different shaders, one which does only textures and another which does only colors (and switch between them using `gl.useProgram` between objects).
- You could use only textures, and color objects using a 1×1 texture containing the desired color (if you want a uniform color, not a per-vertex color).

All of these and more are perfectly fine ways to solve the problem. Do whichever one is most convenient for the rest of your program. If you're concerned about performance, then try them and choose the fastest.